# Using dilation in only one direction?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-morphology, dilation

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so I am sorry if the problem isn't defined enough.

I am currently working on extracting table data from images and I need a way to dilate the text only in a vertical direction so that I can get clear column representation that will be used for further segmentation.

After removing horizontal and vertical lines and transforming the image bitwise, I am at this stage:

[image: Current state after dilation and line extraction]

The ideal goal for this problem would be:

[image: The goal]

Is there a method or an algorithm that would be helpful in my case?

Comment: When using [`cv2.dilate`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga4ff0f3318642c4f469d0e11f242f3b6c), you can set up a custom `kernel`. Use a `3 x 1` (rows x columns) white rectangle here, and set `iterations` large enough.

Comment: Maybe you can dilate by a vertical kernel with width of 1. I don't know if it works, but I think that should dilate only on vertical direction.

Comment: Thank You, I will try that.

Comment: You can also set a kernel with a reasonable height and perform only one iteration (see my answer below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just call `cv2.dilate` with the appropriate structuring element.

```py
import cv2

pre_img = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
h, w = pre_img.shape

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, ksize=(1, 2 * h))

dilated = cv2.dilate(pre_img, kernel)

cv2.imshow('input', pre_img)
cv2.imshow('output', dilated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Input**
[image: input image]

**Output**
[image: output image]

To visualize better what's happening:

```py
blended = (pre_img.astype(float) + dilated.astype(float)) / 2
cv2.imshow('blended', blended.astype(np.uint8))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Blended**
[image: image blend]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you don’t want a dilation, but a maximum projection. For each column, check to see if any pixel is set. Use [numpy.any](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) for that:

```
result = np.any(image, axis=0)
```

Comment: This is much more efficient than using a convolution approach. Maybe add a `.reshape(image.shape)` at the end to get the 2D image, depending on the use case.

Comment: @Rob `np.tile` would be more suited to convert the projection back into a 2D image. Might be necessary or not depending on subsequent operations. Implicit broadcasting might make it unnecessary.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. It should be `np.tile(np.any(image, axis=0), (image.shape[0], 1))`. I agree that it is usually not needed.